# Simplest way to implement one-method interfaces in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, closures

What is the simplest way to implement one-method interfaces in Groovy?

Ones, like [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html)?

For example, to list files I wrote java-like:

```
// works Java-like
new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File file) {
        !file.isDirectory()
    }
}).each { println it.absolutePath }
```

but closure-like does not work

```
// does not work
new File(".").listFiles({file -> !file.isDirectory()}).each { println it.absolutePath }
```

Is it possible to implement it using closures or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular example the following piece of code should work:

```
return [downloadFolder: downloadFolder.listFiles({ file ->
           return !file.isDirectory()
       })]
```

Basically interfaces can be implemented using a `Map`.

**EDIT**
In this particular example it should be:

```
new File(".").listFiles({file -> !file.isDirectory()} as FileFilter).each { println it.absolutePath }
```

Comment: How can it know, that `{file -> !file.isDirectory()}` should implement namely `FileFilter`? Does it infer types here?

Comment: It will be run dynamically.

Comment: What if I had ambiguous types, say `FileFilter` and `FileFilter2` with the same code

Comment: Do you have an example? You can use `as` keyword in such situation.

Comment: Is not working BTW. Says can't distinguish `FileFilter` and `FilenameFilter`.

Comment: Please use `as` operator than.

Comment: Please, have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/Opalo/5157a9449a471e83d1d3#file-gistfile1-txt) gist.

Comment: The following does not work: `new File(".").listFiles({file -> !isDirectory()} as FileFilter).each { println it.absolutePath }` also

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. It should be: `new File(".").listFiles({file -> !file.isDirectory()} as FileFilter).each { println it.absolutePath }`

Comment: You can simplify it by using:
`new File(".").listFiles( {!it.isDirectory()} as FileFilter).each {println it.absolutePath}`